# ipad share by email subject line - set subject line

Tags: ipad, file, email, share, subject

Is there any way to set an email subject line for say a document at
http://www.mydomain.com/Download.aspx?InstanceID=1087&Type=doc

Now when I hit share and try to send it from an iPad, the subject line is:
"http://www.mydomain.com/Download.aspx?InstanceID=1087&Type=doc"

When it should be customized by document: "Application Form", "Waiver Form", etc.

Do I set this in acrobat (it is a pdf) or is there some code I can use?

Thanks

Comment: Did my below suggestion worked for you?

Answer (score 0):

Check below code for the email for setting up your email subject:

```
UIActivityViewController* avc = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:@[@"Your String to share"]
                                  applicationActivities:nil];
[avc setValue:@"Your email Subject" forKey:@"subject"];

avc.completionHandler = ^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    // ...
};
```

Here the line

> [avc setValue:@"Your email Subject" forKey:@"subject"];

Makes the subject as "Your email Subject" if user picks email option in the UIActivityViewController.

I hope it helps...